# What's the cross ratio of 4 planes?

Tags: projective-geometry

For example, 
$H_1 : 3X_0 + 2X_3 = 0\\H_2 : −X_0 − X_1 + X_2 = 0\\H_3 : 4X_0 + X_1 −
X_2 + 2X_3 = 0\\H_4 : 5X_0 + 2X_1 − 2X_2 + 2X_3 = 0$

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: No book, it's an excercise our teacher told us to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have a common line, find the normals of the planes and treat them as if they are a pencil of lines.  Compute the cross ratio of those lines (using the usual ratio of sines of angles).  Or, for fun, [compute a ratio of cross products](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642903).